# perl how to grab spesific string in paragraph style

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array

I'm new on perl and still learning by doing some case. I've some case on parsing a log with perl.

There is a data log :

```
Physical interface: ge-1/0/2, Unit: 101, Vlan-id: 101, Address: 10.187.132.3/27
  Index: 353, SNMP ifIndex: 577, VRRP-Traps: enabled
  Interface state: up, Group: 1, State: backup, VRRP Mode: Active
  Priority: 190, Advertisement interval: 1, Authentication type: none
  Advertisement threshold: 3, Delay threshold: 100, Computed send rate: 0
  Preempt: yes, Accept-data mode: yes, VIP count: 1, VIP: 10.187.132.1       
  Dead timer: 2.715s, Master priority: 200, Master router: 10.187.132.2 
  Virtual router uptime: 5w5d 12:54
  Tracking: disabled 

Physical interface: ge-1/0/2, Unit: 102, Vlan-id: 102, Address: 10.187.132.35/27
  Index: 354, SNMP ifIndex: 580, VRRP-Traps: enabled
  Interface state: up, Group: 2, State: master, VRRP Mode: Active
  Priority: 200, Advertisement interval: 1, Authentication type: none
  Advertisement threshold: 3, Delay threshold: 100, Computed send rate: 0
  Preempt: yes, Accept-data mode: yes, VIP count: 1, VIP: 10.187.132.33      
  Advertisement Timer: 0.816s, Master router: 10.187.132.35
  Virtual router uptime: 5w5d 12:54, Master router uptime: 5w5d 12:54
  Virtual Mac: 00:00:5e:00:01:02 
  Tracking: disabled 

Physical interface: ge-1/0/2, Unit: 103, Vlan-id: 103, Address: 10.187.132.67/27
  Index: 355, SNMP ifIndex: 581, VRRP-Traps: enabled
  Interface state: up, Group: 3, State: backup, VRRP Mode: Active
  Priority: 190, Advertisement interval: 1, Authentication type: none
  Advertisement threshold: 3, Delay threshold: 100, Computed send rate: 0
  Preempt: yes, Accept-data mode: yes, VIP count: 1, VIP: 10.187.132.65      
  Dead timer: 2.624s, Master priority: 200, Master router: 10.187.132.66 
  Virtual router uptime: 5w5d 12:54
  Tracking: disabled
```

I curious how we can retrieve some value and store it to array. I've tried grep it but I'm confuse how to take a spesific value.

Expected Value on Array of Hashes:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2.101',
          'address' => '10.187.132.3/27',
          'State' => 'backup'
          'Master-router' => '10.187.132.2'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2.102',
          'address' => '10.187.132.35/27',
          'State' => 'master'
          'Master-router' => '10.187.132.35'
        };
$VAR3 = {
          'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2.103',
          'address' => '10.187.132.67/27',
          'State' => 'backup'
          'Master-router' => '10.187.132.66'
        };
```

Comment: Do post up what you have, even if it doesn't work. That way, we'll know you've tried something

Comment: Perhaps you should also describe exactly what you want from this log, unless you want people to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to split each paragraph up. Something like this might work:

```
/((\w|\s|-)+):\s([^,]+)/m
```

The matching groups would then look something like:

```
Match 1
1.  Physical interface
2.  e
3.  ge-1/0/2
Match 2
1.  Unit
2.  t
3.  101
Match 3
1.  Vlan-id
2.  d
3.  101
```

As you can see *1.* corresponds to a key whereas *3.* is the corresponding value. You can store the set of pairs any way you like.

For this to work each attribute in the log would need to be comma-seperated, which the example you have listed isn't. Assuming the example you have listed is correct, you would have to adjust the regex a little to make it work. You can test it online at [rubular](http://rubular.com/) until it works. If it is comma seperated you might just want to split each paragraph by "," and then split each result on ":".

**EDIT:**

It seems to me like each line is comma seperated so the methods mentioned above might work perfectly well if you use them on a single line at a time.

Comment: There is no need to capture group no 2. You can use `(?:\w|\s|-)` or simply `[\w\s-]` instead of `(\w|\s|-)`

Answer (score 0):

To parse the data:

1. Obtain a section from the file by reading lines into a section while the lines start with whitespace.
2. Split the sections at the item separators which are either commas or linebreaks
3. Split each item at the first colon into a key and value
4. Case-fold the key and store the pair into a hash

A sketch of an implementation:

```
my @hashes;
while (<>) {
  push @hashes, {} if /\A\S/;
  for my $item (split /,/) {
    my ($k, $v) = split /:/, $item, 2;
    $hashes[-1]{fc $k} = $v;
  }
}
```

Then you can extract those pieces of information from the hash which you are interested in.

Comment: You should probably use a limit of 2 in your split.

Answer (score 0):

Since each record is a *paragraph*, you can have Perl read the file in those chunks by `local $/ = '';` (*paragraph mode*).  Then, use a regex to capture each value that you want within that paragraph, pair that value with a hash key, and then `push` a reference to that hash onto an array to form an array of hashes (AoH):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr;
local $/ = '';

while (<DATA>) {
    my %hash;
    ( $hash{'interface'} )     = /interface:\s+([^,]+)/;
    ( $hash{'address'} )       = /Address:\s+(\S+)/;
    ( $hash{'State'} )         = /State:\s+([^,]+)/;
    ( $hash{'Master-router'} ) = /Master router:\s+(\S+)/;

    push @arr, \%hash;
}

print Dumper \@arr;

__DATA__
Physical interface: ge-1/0/2, Unit: 101, Vlan-id: 101, Address: 10.187.132.3/27
  Index: 353, SNMP ifIndex: 577, VRRP-Traps: enabled
  Interface state: up, Group: 1, State: backup, VRRP Mode: Active
  Priority: 190, Advertisement interval: 1, Authentication type: none
  Advertisement threshold: 3, Delay threshold: 100, Computed send rate: 0
  Preempt: yes, Accept-data mode: yes, VIP count: 1, VIP: 10.187.132.1       
  Dead timer: 2.715s, Master priority: 200, Master router: 10.187.132.2
  Virtual router uptime: 5w5d 12:54
  Tracking: disabled 

Physical interface: ge-1/0/2, Unit: 102, Vlan-id: 102, Address: 10.187.132.35/27
  Index: 354, SNMP ifIndex: 580, VRRP-Traps: enabled
  Interface state: up, Group: 2, State: master, VRRP Mode: Active
  Priority: 200, Advertisement interval: 1, Authentication type: none
  Advertisement threshold: 3, Delay threshold: 100, Computed send rate: 0
  Preempt: yes, Accept-data mode: yes, VIP count: 1, VIP: 10.187.132.33      
  Advertisement Timer: 0.816s, Master router: 10.187.132.35
  Virtual router uptime: 5w5d 12:54, Master router uptime: 5w5d 12:54
  Virtual Mac: 00:00:5e:00:01:02 
  Tracking: disabled 

Physical interface: ge-1/0/2, Unit: 103, Vlan-id: 103, Address: 10.187.132.67/27
  Index: 355, SNMP ifIndex: 581, VRRP-Traps: enabled
  Interface state: up, Group: 3, State: backup, VRRP Mode: Active
  Priority: 190, Advertisement interval: 1, Authentication type: none
  Advertisement threshold: 3, Delay threshold: 100, Computed send rate: 0
  Preempt: yes, Accept-data mode: yes, VIP count: 1, VIP: 10.187.132.65      
  Dead timer: 2.624s, Master priority: 200, Master router: 10.187.132.66
  Virtual router uptime: 5w5d 12:54
  Tracking: disabled
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Master-router' => '10.187.132.2',
            'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2',
            'address' => '10.187.132.3/27',
            'State' => 'backup'
          },
          {
            'Master-router' => '10.187.132.35',
            'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2',
            'address' => '10.187.132.35/27',
            'State' => 'master'
          },
          {
            'Master-router' => '10.187.132.66',
            'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2',
            'address' => '10.187.132.67/27',
            'State' => 'backup'
          }
        ];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for "State:" , somehow it doesn't fetch the value..

$VAR1 = {
          'Master-router' => undef,
          'interface' => 'ge-1/0/2',
          'address' => '10.187.132.3/27',
          'State' => undef
        };

Comment: @warkomers - It does capture the wanted fields in your three shown data blocks.  In which data block do the captures fail?  Perhaps there's a block with different labeling.  If you would, please append that data block in question to your original data set, and let me know when you've done this.